# make: f77: No such file or directory

Tags: xcode, macos, fortran

Whilst attempting to make/compile the grafic package, I'm seeing this error after calling the make command within the grafic directory:

```
f77 -O2 -c grafic1.f
make: f77: No such file or directory
make: *** [grafic1.o] Error 1
```

I have XCode and all associated command line tools installed, what could be causing this error?

Comment: A lack of a Fortran compiler, not part of the standard distribution of Xcode nor of its related command-line tools, could be causing that error.  Did you install a Fortran compiler ?

Answer (score 2):

This error is `make` telling you that you have no binary in your path called `f77`.  There are two things you need to look at the fix this:

1. Do you have a Fortran compiler installed?  MacOS X/Xcode does not come pre-installed with one by default.  The easiest options to install one are via third-party tools like [macports](https://www.macports.org/) or [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) where you can install `gfortran` which may be a standalone package or may be part of the `gcc` package.
2. Once you have a compiler installed, your makefile needs to know about it.  Without seeing the makefile this is only an assumption, but if autotools are not used the fortran compiler is usually hardcoded in a variable called `FC`, e.g. you might see a line

   ```
   FC=f77
   ```

   and you would change this to

   ```
   FC=gfortran
   ```

   assuming `gfortran` is in your path.

Once you have a Fortran compiler installed and the makefile knows about it, you should be able to execute `make` successfully.

Comment: Which makefile??