# make[1]: exec(f77) failed (No such file or directory) on DragonFly BSD

Tags: makefile, fortran, bsd, dragonfly-bsd, html-xml-utils

I get this error when trying to compile `html-xml-utils-6.9` on DragonFly BSD. Funny thing is, when doing `grep -r f77` in the source directory, the result is empty. So no such option is in the constructed Makefile after `./configure`.

This is my configure output: http://pastebin.com/4tKEXQKG

I tried to do `alias f77="gfortran48"`, but the problem remains. `gfortran48` is an installed compiler, I've checked with `man gfortran48`.

My full error output:

```
/home/olle2/Downloads/html-xml-utils-6.9$ make
make  all-am
f77    -O -c html.e
make[1]: exec(f77) failed (No such file or directory)
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make[1]: stopped in /home/olle2/Downloads/html-xml-utils-6.9
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /home/olle2/Downloads/html-xml-utils-6.9
```

Any ideas?

Related thread: [make: f77: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832366/make-f77-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: `man gfortran48` doesn't check anything about the compiler being installed, not really, it just checks that a man page for it exists. `command -v gfortran48` will see whether a file by that name exists in your current `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this line:

```
./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib -liconv" && gmake && echo $?
```

(`gmake` instead of `make` gives saner error messages.)

Thanks to `#dragonflybsd` IRC channel!

Answer (score 0):

Aliases aren't available to non-interactive shells generally so an alias isn't the right solution to this problem.

The default `FC` make variable is `f77` so that is likely what is in use in the makefile. This also indicates your solution.

Try `make FC=gfortran48` or similar.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem was something completely different. See my answer below.